# PHP echoing without echo

Tags: php

Very simple code:

```
<?php
$last_line = system('pwsh -Command (Get-Location).path', $retval);
```

Returning string on html page:
[image]

How is this possible and how to avoid it?

Comment: Behaves as documented. Did you read the documentation of that function you used and perhaps a few related ones?

Comment: Said documentation  http://php.net/system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP `system()` command executing a system command and print immediately the output out. To avoid that you can use `exec()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ob_start()` to save the output of the command in a buffer. Then use `ob_clean()` in order to clear that buffer without printing it.

```
ob_start(); 
$last_line = system('pwsh -Command (Get-Location).path', $retval);
ob_clean();
```

Comment: This is correct - but needs some words describing the solution. PHP docs for output buffers are here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: While it works, there are functions other than `system` that don't flush the output directly to begin with, which don't require this workaround…